# Extra space with <i> inside <button>

Tags: html, css, icons

I often use iconic fonts, and often face the same issue when I try to put an icon inside a button.

I've got an extra space, a̶n̶d̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶e̶s̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶:

*EDIT:*
You can see in this snippet the last button has not the same height as the previous one. This is caused by the default `font-size` applied in the iconic font. [A solution first provided by Tibbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296013/1238019) was to set the `line-height` property. It works, but the button is then no longer vertically aligned.
So here comes the question :

**How to change a button font size, preserving its height and keeping it vertically aligned ?**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input,
button {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
button i:before {
    content: "\25b6";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="VALUE">
<button>SEND</button>
<button><i></i></button>
```

Does somebody know where I should look ?

To illustrate what I'm searching, I made several screens :

1. Without change

[image]

2. With `line-height: 0;`

[image]

3. With `vertical-align: middle;`

[image]

4. With `line-height: 0; vertical-align: middle;`

[image]

5. **Expected**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean extra space?

Comment: See the snippet, heights don't fit.

Comment: remove the float:left; from the class (input, button)

Comment: @Aru Sure it works. Unfortunately, I need this `float: left` to manage margins.

Comment: why cant you use 'display:inline-block' instead of 'float:left'?

Comment: @Aru When you put a `display-block` element next another one, you've got a non-manageable margin between them. I need to manage it.

Comment: agreed!! to avoid that, we can set "font-size:0" to the parent element..

Comment: check this fiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/ouzw4y9a/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? Just add `display:block` to your `i:before` and the `line-height` in the `input` to make all the 3 elements aligned.

I added `line-height:20px` to your `i:before` because I reset the `line-height` to 0 in `*`

See snippet below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0
}
input,
button {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
input {
  line-height: 22px;
}
button i:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="VALUE">
<button>SEND</button>
<button><i></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Finally, I agree. Simply adding `display: block` seems the easiest/cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted it out be setting up the `line-height` to the `i:before` element

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    input,
    button {
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        float: left;
     
    }
    button i:before {
        content: "\25b6";
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 15px;
        font-style: normal; 
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" value="VALUE">
    <button>SEND</button>
    <button><i></i></button>
```

Comment: Sounds great... I may use `line-height: 0` on the whole font icons.

Comment: Not sure if `line-height: 0` will help but you must play around it and try. Glad it was useful and good luck.

Comment: It brings another problem : icon is no longer vertical aligned. I should simply change `font-size`, but it's not the 'good' solution. I keep searching.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and provide more information why it's not a `good` solution? Obviously it's quickfix but still, I'm using this technique and didn't faced any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just add line-height: 0 to the i:before :)

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
input,
button {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button i:before {
    content: "\25b6";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal; 
    line-height: 0px;
    
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="VALUE">
<button>SEND</button>
<button><i></i></button>
```

Comment: I don't want them to be `inline-block` displayed, as it brings another common problem : non-manageable margin *between* elements.

Comment: Just add line-height 0 i:before and it will work, check updated answer :) Also I added a fix for firefox not even line heights of inputs and buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that particular charachter (▶) is not vertically centered... just try to select it to understand what I mean.

i guess you can correct it placing it with `line-height:20px` (same as text in the button), `vertical-align:middle` and a litte negative margin on top... if you use em units for this property you can change the dimension of the font and it will be still working... i think that a `margin-top:-0.1em;` is enough.

here the complete solution

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input,
button {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
button i:before {
    content: "\25b6";
    font-size: 20px;
  line-height:20px;
    font-style: normal;
  display:block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-top:-0.1em;
  margin-bottom:0.1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="VALUE">
<button>SEND</button>
<button><i></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixin answers and testing my own ideas, I finally came to a suitable solution.

First, I discovered the `\25b6` character is not *perfectly* vertically aligned. It's a few pixel under the middle line. So I made tries with other characters to be sure.

Here's my solution :

- Use `height: 40px` instead of `line-height: 20px` on `input, button` (40 = line-height + padding-top + padding-bottom)
- Add `display: table; line-height: 0;` to `i`. The `i` element itself had a default line-height and this size was pushing down the `i:before` element.
- Add `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to `i:before`

Final code :

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input,
button {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
button i {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}
button i:before {
    content: "\25b6";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal; 
    line-height: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="VALUE">
<button>SEND</button>
<button><i></i></button>
```

Comment: with less changes I came to the same result ;)

Comment: Put `button i:before {font-size: 40px;}` to see the difference.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer, from `display:table` to `display:block` and now the `font-size:40px` doesn't make any changes. I didn't know that you wanted your arrow bigger than your question ;) IMO if you have `font-size:40px`, it looks better in my snippet than yours. since the output of yours is 40w*18h and mine is 40w*22h

Comment: @zessx your result is still closer to the 4th image in the question rather than the 5th (expected)